# Is there a way to put multiple ranges in one if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, ascii

I'm new at c and stack overflow please forgive my amateur mistakes if there are some...

I'm trying to accept digits between 0 and 9, uppercase letters and lowercase letters in my code. So ascii codes between 48-57 or 65-90 or 98-122. There is also a previous part of the code containing the menu. I did not include it for brevity.

This is the first thing i tried:

```
int main()
{

char n;

printf("\n\nWhich code will you use?: ");
scanf("%c",&n);

if (n<=57 && n>=57 || n<=65 && n>=95 || n<=98 && n>= 122)
   printf("Binary equivalent..");
                                                             /*there is supposed to be a whole another
                                                              section here.. however i haven't completed 
                                                              that yet. I put a print statement to make 
                                                              sure if the if statement would work...*/
else
   printf("Wrong input..");
}
...
```

This gives the result of "wrong input" whatever i input ( I inputed c, a and 4).

The second thing i tried was to put parenthesis:

```
...

if ((n<=48 && n>=57 )||( n<=65 && n>=95 )||( n<=98 && n>= 122))

...
```

Then i tried changing the "%c" to a "%d" which didn't change anything either.

```
...

printf("\n\nWhich code will you use?: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

...
```

The only thing that worked was to seperate each relation into three different if statements. However i'm going to be writing the same thing in every if statement which i feel like makes my code unnecessarily long...

Comment: Do you know what `n<=48 && n>=57` means?

Comment: Your number are off and also use the character not its code for readability like `n >= '0' && n <= '9'`. Also I would put parenthesizes around these checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You messed up the relations direction, and you could also use the character literals. Try this

```
if ((n >= '0' && n <= '9') || (n >= 'A' && n <= 'Z' ) || (n >= 'a' && n <= 'z'))
```

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't think of trying this because we haven't learned strings yet..!

Comment: @YıldızAlaraKöymen The characters aren't what solves the problem. It could be `if ((n >= 48 && n <= 57) || (n >= 65 && ....`

Comment: @YıldızAlaraKöymen [because we haven't learned strings yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420044/is-there-a-way-to-put-multiple-ranges-in-one-if-statement#comment106885842_60420322) --> Note: there are no _strings_ in `if ((n >= '0' && n <= '9') ....`

Answer (score 1):

#### ASCII values

Digits (`0-9`): `48`-`57`
Uppercase letters (`A-Z`): `65`-`90`
Lowercase letters (`a-z`): `97`-`122`

#### Conditions

`c >= 48 && c <= 57`: `true` if `c` is a digit
`c >= 65 && c <= 90`: `true` if `c` is an uppercase letter
`c >= 97 && c <= 122`: `true` if `c` is a lowercase letter

`(c >= 48 && c <= 57) || (c >= 65 && c <= 90) || (c >= 97 && c <= 122)`: true if `c` is alphanumeric (a letter or a digit)

But it is much easier to use `'a'` instead of `97`, because you don't need to learn the whole ASCII table by heart that way.

#### Notes

`n<=48 && n>=57` will always be `false`. If you pause for a second, you'll realise that no number (in the ASCII table or not) can be less than `48` and greater than `57` at the same time.